# How to enable OpenEdge debugger?

Tags: debugging, openedge, progress-4gl

I have enabled the debugger with `prodebugenable -enable-all` as mentioned here: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/pdsoe%2Fenabling-debugging.html%23wwID0EBCZX

I have got the success message

> Debugging is enabled for the Progress 4GL installed in ...

But I still get the error

> The Progress 4GL is not enabled for debugging. Run proDebugEnable from
>   within a proenv session on Windows or from a UNIX shell to enable
>   debugging and set the debuggerEnabled property to 1 for any services
>   that you want to debug. (11724)

prodebugenable.bat runs the exe file _debugEnable.exe. What does this file do?

Why the debugger isn't enabled although I get a success message ?

My Version: OpenEdge 10.2B

Comment: were you admin when enabling? if not it might be worth retrying as admin login

Comment: Yes, i was admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLC path was wrong in the ini-file. After I corrected it as in the registry the debugging worked.

Comment: You shouldnt post comments as an answer - upvote and star if you're happy with the answer. Comment if you want to clarify anything.

Comment: This IS the answer. The answer of Stefan Drissen has not solve my problem. It only helped me to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

All that prodebugenable does is create a registry entry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PSC\PROGRESS\ProDbgCK\<DLC>.state
```

or when using a 32-bit version on a 64-bit Windows installation at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\PSC\PROGRESS\ProDbgCK\<DLC>.state
```

Containing the string value 'Debugging enabled'

In which `<DLC>` is the path to your Progress OpenEdge installation.